# How to resolve :The attribute ' ' in the dimension ' ' is outside the granularity of the measure group ' ' and cannot be returned as a column

Tags: c#, devexpress, mdx, olap, olap-cube

I am facing a problem of drilling through for hierarchical dimensional group inside OLAP Cube.
As soon as this dimension is involved in drilling through, I am getting the error :

> Errors from the SQL query module: The attribute 'Cost Group Id' in the
>   dimension 'ConsignmentCost' is outside the granularity of the measure
>   group 'Cube Consignment' and cannot be returned as a column.

My Cube is as follows :

> Measures:

---

M1

M2
..

> Dimensions:

---

Consignment

---

Consignment.Field1

Consignment.Field2
..................

Cost

---

Cost.Field1

Cost.Field2  ( Error thrown , when on of the following field is referred in drillthrough ).

```
Cost.Field2.Group  
Cost.Field.Cost Type
```

..........

Period

---

Period.Field1

Period.Field2

Comment: I feel more detail will be required if you want an answer to this question.

Comment: also you might have more responses if you also post this question to the SSAS forum run by Microsoft.